# Java EE Web services: Naming conflict

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, weblogic, wsimport

I'm trying to create Web services proxies with wsimport, but I get an error because of a conflict. "Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class."

I've got two EJBs with Webservices deployed in one ear. Both have a method with the same name and parameters. Each WS has it's own targetnamespace.

SEI of WS A:

```
@Local
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
@WebService(name = "AService", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/bla/a")
public interface ASEI {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "erpId")
    public Long getId(@WebParam(name = "gid")
    Long gid);
}
```

WebService A:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(serviceName = "AWebService",
        endpointInterface = "foo.endpointinterfaces.ASEI",
        targetNamespace = "http://example.com/bla/a")
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class AWebService implements ASEI {

     public Long getId(Long gid) { ... }
}
```

SEI of WS B:

```
@Local
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL,     parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
@WebService(name = "BService", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/bla/b")
public interface BSEI {

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name = "erpId")
    public Long getId(@WebParam(name = "gid")
    Long gid);
}
```

Webservice B:

```
@Stateless
@WebService(serviceName = "BWebService",
        endpointInterface = "foo.endpointinterfaces.ASEI",
        targetNamespace = "http://example.com/bla/b")
@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
public class BWebService implements BSEI {

     public Long getId(Long gid) { ... }
}
```

When I deploy the application to my Weblogic server, the first Webservices imports the xml declarations of WS B and uses them for the message types.

WSDL of A:

```
<definitions targetNamespace="http://example.com/bla/a" name="AWebService" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/bla/a" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
<types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://example.com/bla/b" schemaLocation="http://192.168.178.105:7001/BWebService/AWebService?xsd=1"/>
    </xsd:schema>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import namespace="http://example.com/bla/a" schemaLocation="http://192.168.178.105:7001/AWebService/AWebService?xsd=2"/>
    </xsd:schema>
</types>

<message name="getId">
    <part name="parameters" element="tns:getId"/>
</message>
...
```

XSD=1:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://example.com/bla/b" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/bla/b" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="getId" type="tns:getId"/>
    <xs:complexType name="getId"> ... </xs:complexType>
    ...
```

XSD=2:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://example.com/bla/a" xmlns:tns="http://example.com/bla/a" xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/bla/b" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:import namespace="http://example.com/bla/b" schemaLocation="http://192.168.178.105:7001/AWebService/AWebService?xsd=1"/>
    <xs:element name="getId" nillable="true" type="ns1:getId"/>
    ...
```

Is there a way that each WS defines it's own messagetypes? Or what else can I do, to create a WS proxy? (I don't want to separate them into different Java EE-Applications.)

Comment: Chris, if my answer below is helpful, it would be cool if you click the check mark and "accept" it as the right answer.  We both get Stackoverflow reputation points when you do this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be having a similar problem as I did.  But, I'm not totally sure, so this is just a guess at an answer.

I found that a binding file that did some class customization fixed my issue with elements and complexTypes that had matching names across multiple schemas that were referenced in a singular wsdl file just like you have in your example above.

In XSD=1 you have

```
<xs:complexType="getId"> and <xs:element name="getId" ...>
```

And, in XSD=2 you have

```
<xs:element name="getId" ...>
```

So, to fix this I used something like this in my binding file...

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.0"
           xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="http://192.168.178.105:7001/BWebService/AWebService?xsd=1" node="//xs:element[@name='getId']">
       <jxb:class name="getIdElement"></jxb:class>
   </jxb:bindings> 
</jxb:bindings>
```

This solved my issue of having the same name for a ***complexType*** and an ***element***.  Since you have the same name for multiple elements in two xsd files with different namespaces, I'm not even sure if this will help that problem.

There's a lot more info about possible collision problems and their solutions here... http://goo.gl/vlQe3

Good Luck,
TW